# Pasting content from clipboard using mozilla navigator

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm trying to paste data from the clipboard into an element. Note: i do not need to deal with copying to the clipboard, just reading the content (if any) and pasting.

I have read the mozilla docs on the clipboard and permissions, but they don't seem to be working:

```
 $('#btn-paste-clipboard').on('click', function(e){
    navigator.permissions.query({name:'clipboard-read'}).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.state);
        if(result.state === 'granted'){
            console.log(navigator.clipboard.readText());
        }
    });
});
```

No output is sent to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the same issue and looking at the documentation from Mozilla, the 'clipboard-read' permission is yet to be implemented in the current version of Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thanks, i assumed the functionality was already in place, but clearly not.